# show hidden div onclick from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have Two pages. One is

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
  function toggleDiv(divid){
   if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none'){
  document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
}else{
  document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a name="div1" href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('div1');"><p><b>Section 1</b>      </p></a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Content for section 1.
</div>
<a name="div2" href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('div2');"><p><b>Section 2</b></p></a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Content for section 2.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On other page I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="main.html#iv2">Section 2</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    toggleDiv( location.hash.substring(1) );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I like to achieve here is, when I click on "Section 2" on the second page, main page will open with "div2" content displayed. The above code doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

d is missing in id

```
<a href="main.html#div2">Section 2</a>
```

and this script should be in  page 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    toggleDiv( location.hash.substring(1) );
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help

this is complete code of your page 1 (main.html)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<a name="div1" href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('div1');"><p><b>Section 1</b>      </p></a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Content for section 1.
</div>
<a name="div2" href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('div2');"><p><b>Section 2</b></p></a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Content for section 2.
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    toggleDiv( location.hash.substring(1));
}
 function toggleDiv(divid){
  alert(divid);
   if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none'){
  document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
}else{
  document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this  and let u know

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Javascript function Like that...That won't work...you need to call the function inthe onLoad Event of the Page...like

```
<body onload="toggleDiv('div2')"> 
</body>
```

**Else**

Open The Popup and Use "Window opener" property.See this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp